# C# when trying to add a next button geting negative value error

Tags: c#, client

Creating a client server application i have managed to get the server to link to the database and send all the records over to the client and it shows the first record in all the correct text boxes but when i try and click on my next button it shows the error

"Index was out of range.Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index"

Heres the code i am using for this

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        client c1;
        int counter = 0;
        string results = "";
        List<House> loadedHouses = new List<House>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            c1 = new client();
            c1.runClient();
            textBox1 = Convert.ToString(Counter);


        }

        private int _counter; //It defaults to 0, setting it to 0 is redundant.
        public int Counter
        {
            get { return _counter; }
            set
        {
            if (Equals(_counter, value)) return;

            if (value < 0) return;

            if ((loadedHouses != null) && (value > loadedHouses.Count)) return;

            _counter = value;

            GetHouse();
        }
        }



        private void GetFirst()
        {
            Counter = 0;
        }
        private void Getprevious()
        {
            Counter--;
        }
        private void Getnext()
        {
            Counter++;
            GetHouse();
        }
        private void Getlast()
        {
           Counter = ((loadedHouses == null) ? 0 : loadedHouses.Count);
        }



        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Funsold_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Fsold_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Fall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string aQuery = "SELECT * FROM houses";


            string result = c1.getStringfromServer(aQuery);

            string[] Rows = result.Split('*');

            //try
            //{

                foreach (string r in Rows)
                {



                    string[] h = new string[5];
                    h = r.Split(',');
                    MessageBox.Show(h[0]);
                    // need to show the first record
                    House newhouse = new House();
                    if (h[0] == "")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("ARRRHHHJJJ CRASH!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newhouse.ID = int.Parse(h[0]);


                    newhouse.Address = Convert.ToString(h[1]);
                    newhouse.Type = Convert.ToChar(h[2]);
                    newhouse.Cost = int.Parse(h[3]);
                    newhouse.Sold = Convert.ToString(h[4]);

                    loadedHouses.Add(newhouse);

                    ID_Number.Text = Convert.ToString(h[0]);

                    address1.Text = Convert.ToString(h[1]);
                    type1.Text = Convert.ToString(h[2]);
                    cost1.Text = Convert.ToString(h[3]);
                    sold1.Text = Convert.ToString(h[4]);



                    }
                    }

        //    }

        //        catch (Exception qq)
        //{
        //    MessageBox.Show (qq.Message);
        //}

            }
        public void GetHouse()
        {
            int m = Counter;
            House thisHouse = Counter < loadedHouses.Count ? loadedHouses[Counter] : null;

            ID_Number.Text = Convert.ToString(thisHouse.ID);
            address1.Text = Convert.ToString(thisHouse.Address);
            type1.Text = Convert.ToString(thisHouse.Type);
            cost1.Text = Convert.ToString(thisHouse.Cost);
            sold1.Text = Convert.ToString(thisHouse.Sold);
        }

        private void Next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Getnext();
        }

        }
    }
```

Any Ideas?

Thank You

Comment: What are the values of `counter` and `loadedHouses.Count`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anywhere in your code you guarding against going outside the bounds of the array.

Here's a suggestion to fix your issues...

```
    private int _counter; //It defaults to 0, setting it to 0 is redundant.
    public int Counter
    {
        get { return _counter; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(_counter, value)) return;

            if (value < 0) return;

            if ((loadedHouses != null) && (value > loadedHouses.Count) return;

            _counter = value;

            GetHouse();
        }
    }
    ...

    private void GetFirst()
    {
        Counter = 0;
    }
    private void Getprevious()
    {
        Counter--;
    }
    private void Getnext()
    {
        Counter++;
    }
    private void Getlast()
    {
        //Counter = results.Count(); //WTF? Why results.Count() when results is a string??
        Counter = ((loadedHouses == null) ? 0 : loadedHouses.Count);
    }
```

---

Though, you should also disabled/enable the buttons based on if the user **should** be able to click them.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use:

```
House thisHouse = counter < loadedHouses.Count ? loadedHouses[counter] : null
```

I mean: are you sure that your list contain only one record? So when you try to get second, you get the exception...

```
private void Getnext()
{

    if (counter < (loadedHouses.Count - 1))
    {
        counter++;
        GetHouse();
    }
}
```

Comment: arrhhh thats one step closer but on the next line now i get this error

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @BenWilson: are you talking about my first line? Well, if counter is not _good_ that line return **null**, so you have to check `if (thisHouse == null) return;` for example...

Comment: @BenWilson: as a rule, you **always must** check that counter is between 0 and (loadedHouses.Count - 1). You cannot leave this to the case...

Comment: i am getting the records as the first 1 is showing but when i come to click on the next it doesn't seem to go to the next 1? i will refresh all my code of what i have now after all the edits

Comment: `GetNext()` function I posted increases counter and refresh dta only if you can go to next record (i it exists...)

Answer (score 0):

You do not have any elements in loadedHouses. It is getting populated in your Fall_Click handler, which is most likely not getting executed when the Next button is clicked.

**Update**: First off, make sure that you are doing your indexes correctly.

For instance, the line

```
if ((loadedHouses != null) && (value > loadedHouses.Count) return;
```

should be

```
if ((loadedHouses != null) && (value >= loadedHouses.Count) return;
```

Also in your GetLast function, you should have:

```
loadedHouses.Count - 1
```

Comment: Marco is correct that you should be checking your counter against the actual values in loadedHouses. But, your current page lifecycle is never loading any values into loadedHouses, and that is your underlying problem here.

Comment: ok so here is a run of what i do i click the fall button which gets all of the records in the database then when i come the click the next button now after adding in @m-y code nothing is happening now ?

Comment: I apologize, I thought this was a web question. I'll update my answer in a moment...

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can update your getPrevious method to make sure you don't fall into negative values and the vice versa with getnext.

```
private void Getprevious()
        {
            counter--;
            if (counter < 0)
                  counter = 0;
        }
        private void Getnext()
        {
            counter++;
            if (counter > maxvaluesofrecords)
                  counter = max;
            else
                  GetHouse();
        }
```